# Get pixel coordinate inside an image opposed to mouse / cursor position on screen

Tags: vb.net, image, coordinates

Not being too educated on the topic and not able to get to the information I need I am posting the question I am having problems with.

I created a user control that loads an image into a picturebox control (sizemode = autosize) and one of the functions I exercise against the loaded image is to add a "marker" (a little triangle) at the point where I right clicked in the picturebox.

```
Dim HScroll As Integer 'Horizontal Scrollbar position
Dim VScroll As Integer 'Vertical scrollbar position
Dim ImageX As Integer 'Mouse click X-coord
Dim ImageY As Integer 'Mouse click Y-coord


'Mouse click position on image
ImageX = m_PanStartPoint.X
ImageY = m_PanStartPoint.Y
'pnlImageAea scroll bar positions
HScroll = pnlImageArea.HorizontalScroll.Value
VScroll = pnlImageArea.VerticalScroll.Value
```

The scroll positions are stored because the images I load are fairly large images and the scroll positions will allow me to scroll the area of the image into view where I captured the mouse X,Y location.

Unfortunately, the results will be different from system to system depending on what screen the user is using because the controls in the UserControl will resize dynamically depending on the size of the screen.

My question is, is it possible to retrieve the actual point (similar to pixel location) location in the image of where the mouse click event occurred. The idea behind this is to always have the exact location of the coordinates of where the click event occurred, even if the picturebox size is reduced / enlarged, the location will always remain exactly the same.

I am almost certain that capturing the screen coords aren't the correct method as it reflects the mouse position relative to a point on the screen and not a point on the image.

Tino

Comment: the mouseclick event will give you the mouse X Y where the click happened.

Comment: @Plutonix: Relative to what ? To the screen or to the actual location on the image ? As I understand it, it will be the screen X,Y.

Comment: EDIT: The picturebox is inside a Panel control which means I can "pan" the image inside the panel control. My apologies for omitting this important piece of information.

Comment: `Cursor.Position` is relative to the desktop/screen, while the event args are relative to the control.  for a scrolling panel, you will need to adjust and factor in the panel's `AutoScrollPosition`.

Comment: Ah, now I am getting to understand the difference. Thanks for the information Plutonix. I am by no means a MIT candidate, is there a specific algorithm to be used to calculated the factor between the image size (picturebox size) in relation to the size of the Panel control ? Image.width / Panel.width + Image.Height / Panel.Height. Each of which will probably give a different factor since the image is not a true rectangle, nor is the Panel.

Comment: as I said, when the panel is set to scroll large stuff, the `panel.AutoScrollPosition.Y` (and .X) will tell you how much is offscreen.  you'll want to read up on it before messing with it - the value can be negative when it seems like it should be the reverse.